# What is the meaning of バ～ロ～?

Tags: particle-に

What is the meaning of バ～ロ～?
I am watching a Japanese TV drama and the word" バ～ロ～" is translated in the subtitles as "idiot" but I want to know the exact word. I checked it on the internet but I didn't find it.

Comment: It should sound very familiar to anime watchers: 'バーローとは、馬鹿野郎の短縮形である。江戸弁の一つ。「馬鹿野郎」→「ばかやろう」→「ばあろう」→「バーロー」 ' https://dic.nicovideo.jp/a/%E3%83%90%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AD%E3%83%BC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s not a censored form of ばかやろう like a comment on the question originally suggested — it’s a slurred/roughly spoken form of it.

Comment: Comment removed. I was never sure how offensive that word is. The translation in my dictionary is rather rude. But then, Japanese doesn't have swear words in the sense that English does so...